# Symmetries of discrete analytic signals

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft, hilbert-transform, analytic-signal

Defining "analytic" as $x_a[n]$, where $X_a[k] = \text{DFT}(x_a[n])$, and

$$
X_a[k < 0] = 0, \tag{1} \label{1}
$$

what time-domain properties, such as symmetry or norm, are guaranteed for $x_a[n]$?

For example, if $X_a$ is real-valued, then $x_a$ is even-symmetric in real part and odd-symmetric in imaginary. If further $X_a[0] = 0$, then $||x_a\text{.re}|| = ||x_a\text{.im}||$.

---

**"Time-domain properties"** means any description not in terms of $X_a$. *Equivalents* are allowed (e.g. equivalent of $X_a[0] = 0$ is $\sum x_a = 0$). In fact this entire question is finding such an equivalent set of descriptions.

Framed differently, what sort of $x_a$ will correlate to zero with every negative frequency cisoid?

Another requirement is for the description to be "tractable", i.e. sufficiently simple. For example, via Hilbert transform, we can say that the imaginary part of $x_a$ must be overlap-added and $1/t$-weighted real part (I'm unsure this holds in discrete time) - but that's not very useful. Complicated attempts are regardless welcome as they may be insightful.

---

Time-domain discrete Hilbert transform convolves cirularly with the following kernel (centered for display; [code](https://pastebin.com/87yh9SNQ)):

[image]

which is $1/t$-like but even samples zeroed. It's also odd-symmetric. Seems plausible for such convolution to guarantee some symmetry. There's also a [discretized Hilbert transform](https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/PROC.1970.7696) but that won't satisfy $(1)$ (or so it seems; haven't verified).

Note, "symmetric" in this question always means DFT-symmetric.

---

**Exact criterion**:

I seek to answer whether $x$ is related to $x_a$, or $x_a\text{.re}$ to  $x_a\text{.im}$ (or to $x$'s) via any of the following operators, either in general case or with some simplifying assumptions (such as zero mean or real-valuedness of $X_a$):

1. $||A[n]||_p / ||B[n]||_p = K$
2. $A[n] / B[n] = K\ \text{ or }\ e^{j n K}$
3. $\sum (A[n] / B[n]) = K$
4. $n A[n] / B[n] = K\ \text{ or }\ e^{j n K}$
5. $\sum n A[n] / B[n] = K$
6. $A[n/{K_0}] / B[n/{K_1}] = K_2\ \text{ or }\ e^{j n K_2}$
7. $\sum A[n/{K_0}] / B[n/{K_1}] = K_2$
8. $A[n] / B[n - K_0] = K_1\ \text{ or }\ e^{j n K_1}$
9. $A[n] + B[n] = K\ \text{ or }\ e^{j n K}$
10. $A[1:N/2] - A[N/2:][::-1] = 0$
11. $A[1:N/2] + A[N/2:][::-1] = 0$
12. $(A[n])^{K_0} / (B[n])^{K_1} = K_2\ \text{ or }\ e^{j n K_2}$
13. $\sum (A[n])^{K_0} / (B[n])^{K_1} = K_2$

where

- $A$ or $B$ is one of: $x$, $x_a$, or their $\text{.re}$ or $\text{.im}$.
- $K$ is any constant; $K_0, K_1, K_2$ are any (potentially different) constants
- $\sum$ is sum over all $n$
- $||\cdot||_p = \sum |\cdot|^p,\ p \in [0, \infty)$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n = [0, ..., N - 1]$
- $1:N/2 \Leftrightarrow n=[1, \lfloor N/2 \rfloor)$
- $::-1 \Leftrightarrow [n_{\min}, n_{\min} + 1, ..., n_{\max}] \rightarrow [n_{\max}, n_{\max} - 1, ..., n_{\min}]$

Comment: The obvious time-domain property is the relation between real and imaginary parts via the Hilbert transform, which also holds in discrete-time. I'm not sure what else you could be looking for. Does this question replace your previous one?

Comment: @MattL. I seek the _emergent properties_ of this relation. A real input's spectrum is Hermitian-symmetric, for example, though we could stop inquiry at "just take the FT". Since the basis functions are symmetric, and positive and negative frequencies are directly related via conjugation, maybe some convenient property exists - maybe not. -- This question is a more focused version of the other one; I could merge them but it'd become rather long.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon what do you mean by *emergent property*? Is it "critical attributes of biological systems, as understanding the individual parts alone is insufficient to understand or predict system behaviour" by Britannica?

Comment: This is really just "can you list all properties that I do not really care to specify, and I even leave it up to the answerer to declare further constraints", sorry. This is too broad! I think you've got enough leads yourself, and you can never get a *comprehensive* list, because properties can be invented as you go along.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You're not wrong. But it's not same as "unanswerable"; one can either prove that the general case is chaotic, or find special cases that have many applications (e.g. Hermitian symmetry).

Comment: @CathMaillon Closer to [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent/), but looser: akin to describing $e^{-j\omega t_0} X(\omega) \Leftrightarrow x(t - t_0)$.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon No, this is not emergence because of the absence of autonomy. Try to avoid abuse of terminology and make your question more clear and focused.

Comment: @CathMaillon Autonomy is immaterial to my usage; mathematical properties can be emergent. Maybe my definition isn't as common so let's call it "derived" or "consequent"; the idea is, certain relations follow from premises, "premise" here being Fourier Transform and "relation" being time-shift property. For my question it's a special case of the transform which might warrant relations as described for real-valued $X$.

Comment: yes, but the space of consequent properties is unbounded because you leave it up to the reader to define additional conditions from which to derive consequences.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's broad but answerable. If you insist, I've now removed all ambiguity.

Comment: Uff these are a lot of things to check, and yet you completely leave open "some simplifying assumptions": what are these? Am I missing some prior question where you defined that? Have you not been able to check these yourself for truth under these assumptions? (I'm really sorry if I'm still missing something here)

Comment: @mmmm You haven't missed; if I define everything there won't be a question any longer. The idea is, I put some effort, the network complements. -- Indeed I could brute force check every operation, but I'm hoping someone has insights to cut the workload. For the gist on allowed simplifications - put one way, if $x_a$ can be generated via affinely transformed white noise, it qualifies. May elaborate later, but this question's no longer my priority - if none have a clue, it's fine. -- Also cleaned up the list.

Comment: @MattL. Hi Matt, I'm looking for the relationship between the real part and the imaginary part of the Fourier transform of a causal series via the Hilbert transform. Is this what you meant? If so, could you give me some references?